# Add events to google calendar without authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make a booking system with Google Calendar API using JavaScript language , it always need an authentication using OAuth 2 and sign in using google account , but I don't need this step to be from the user side.

I am using this code to insert events to Google Calendar , and it worked but it always need a user consent to sign in with a google account , is there any other way to auto-authenticate one google account to make API calls?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* exported gapiLoaded */
        /* exported gisLoaded */
        /* exported handleAuthClick */
        /* exported handleSignoutClick */

        // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
        const CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id';
        const API_KEY = 'my_api_key';

        // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
        const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest';

        // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
        // included, separated by spaces.
        const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

        let tokenClient;
        let gapiInited = false;
        let gisInited = false;

        document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

        /**
         * Callback after api.js is loaded.
         */
        function gapiLoaded() {
            gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
        }

        /**
         * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
         * discovery doc to initialize the API.
         */
        async function initializeGapiClient() {
            await gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: API_KEY,
                discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
            });
            gapiInited = true;
            maybeEnableButtons();
        }

        /**
         * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
         */
        function gisLoaded() {
            tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                scope: SCOPES,
                callback: 'https://localhost:44381/en/BookAnAppointment', // defined later
            });
            gisInited = true;
            maybeEnableButtons();
        }

        /**
         * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
         */
        function maybeEnableButtons() {
            if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
                document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Sign in the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleAuthClick() {
            $("#authorizationModal").modal('hide');
            tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
                if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                    throw (resp);
                }
                document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
                await listUpcomingEvents();
            };

            if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
                // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
                // when establishing a new session.
                tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
            } else {
                // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
                tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Sign out the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleSignoutClick() {
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            if (token !== null) {
                google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
                gapi.client.setToken('');
                document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
                document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
                document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }

        function MyFunction(val) {

            $('.selectedDate').removeClass("selectedDate");
            $(val).addClass("selectedDate");
            //var test3 = val.getAttribute("data-attr");
            //alert(test3);
            //addEvent();
        };

        /**
         * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
         * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
         * appropriate message is printed.
         */
        async function listUpcomingEvents() {
            let response;
            try {
                const request = {
                    'calendarId': 'primary',
                    'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                    'showDeleted': false,
                    'singleEvents': true,
                    'maxResults': 10,
                    'orderBy': 'startTime',
                };
                response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request);
            } catch (err) {
                document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
                return;
            }

            const events = response.result.items;
            if (!events || events.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No events found.';
                return;
            }
            // Flatten to string to display
            const output = events.reduce(
                (str, event) => `${str}${event.summary} (${event.start.dateTime || event.start.date})\n`,
                'Events:\n');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
        }

        const addEvent = (val) => {
            debugger;
            const desc = "Phone Number: " + $("#BookAnAppointment_Phone").val() + "<br>" + "Company: " + $("#BookAnAppointment_Company").val() + "<br>" + "Job Title: " + $("#BookAnAppointment_JobTitle").val() + "<br>" + "Purpose of contacting: " + $("#BookAnAppointment_PurposeOfContacting").val() + "<br>" + "Message: " + $("#BookAnAppointment_Massage").val();
            const date = $('.selectedDate').attr("data-attr");
            console.log(date);
            const start = document.getElementById("time").value;
            var end;
            var name = $("#BookAnAppointment_Name").val() + " Meeting";
            var Email = $("#BookAnAppointment_Email").val();
            const startTime = new Date(date + "," + start).toISOString();

            if (start == "09:00") {
                end = "09:30";
            }
            else if (start == "09:30") {
                end = "10:00";
            }
            else if (start == "10:00") {
                end = "10:30";
            }
            else if (start == "10:30") {
                end = "11:00";
            }
            else if (start == "11:00") {
                end = "11:30";
            }
            else if (start == "11:30") {
                end = "12:00";
            }
            else if (start == "12:00") {
                end = "12:30";
            }
            else if (start == "12:30") {
                end = "13:00";
            }
            else if (start == "13:00") {
                end = "13:30";
            }
            else if (start == "13:30") {
                end = "14:00";
            }
            else if (start == "14:00") {
                end = "14:30";
            }
            else if (start == "14:30") {
                end = "15:00";
            }
            else if (start == "15:00") {
                end = "15:30";
            }
            else if (start == "15:30") {
                end = "16:00";
            }
            else if (start == "16:00") {
                end = "16:30";
            }
            else if (start == "16:30") {
                end = "17:00";
            }
            const endTime = new Date(date + "," + end).toISOString();

            var event = {
                summary: name,
                location: "Google Meet",
                description: desc,
                start: {
                    dateTime: startTime,
                    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                end: {
                    dateTime: endTime,
                    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                attendees: [
                    { email: Email },
                    { email: "jordansourcebooking@gmail.com" }
                ],
                reminders: {
                    useDefault: false,
                    overrides: [
                        { method: "email", minutes: 24 * 60 },
                        { method: "popup", minutes: 10 }
                    ]
                }
            };

            console.log(event)
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                calendarId: "primary",
                resource: event
            });

            request.execute(function (event) {
                console.log(event.htmlLink);
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Insert into google calendar requires authorization.  There is no way around that the user need to be authoirzed

Comment: i can't even make pre authorization even from the back end or using java script?

Comment: or even using the same account to do the insertion for the event?

Comment: client side JavaScript requires that you be authorized at every season